# MkDocs, mkdocstrings - attach only module docstring

Tags: mkdocs

When I want to attach the docstrings from `bar` module in my documentation, I put

`::: foo.bar`

in the markdown file.

It attaches all the docstrings in the `bar` file - module docstring and `Bar` class docstrings. When I want to attach just `Bar` classes docstrings, the syntax is:

`::: foo.bar.Bar`

Now I'd like to reference only module docstring without the class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `members` option:

```
::: foo.bar
    options:
      members: no
```

See https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#globallocal-options.